# creating account on button click

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

The question is i want to create new account per user on the ethereum blockchain. I want to display a form where in the user will enter information and on clicking register, his account should be created. How can this be done?

Comment: Do you mean create an ethereum wallet or do you mean an account for a service you are creating that is then recorded on the blockchain in some way?

Comment: Basically i want like a login system where user will login. There he can see the amount of ethers he has and can do certain transactions.

Comment: so consider a voting application where i want every voter to login and then cast a vote

Answer (score 1):

With web3, once you are connected to the desired node, execute

`newAddress = web3.personal.newAccount(password)`
 on submit/ click. Of-course, the `password`, to be used in future to unlock account/ send transactions, should be from one of the fields in your form, and this will return the address of the account. Also, make sure your personal api is accessible from web3.

Comment: And then how about log out ?